# Вывод сообщения статуса Bluetooth в ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

Есть вот такая модель:

```
class BTData: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {
private var centralManager: CBCentralManager?
override init() {
    super.init()
centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
}

// Получаем состояние при обновлении Central Manager (обязательная)
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager!) {

    var statusMsg = ""
    switch (central.state)
    {
    case .Unsupported:
        statusMsg = "BLE не поддерживается"
    case .Unauthorized:
        statusMsg = "Приложение не авторизовано для использования BLE"
    case .Unknown:
        statusMsg = "Состояние Central Manager не известно"
    case .Resetting:
        statusMsg = "Соединение с системным сервисом потеряно"
    case .PoweredOff:
       statusMsg = "BLE выключено"
    case .PoweredOn:
        statusMsg = "BLE включено"
        statusMsg = "Начинаю сканирование устройств"
        central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
    }
}
```

}

Во ViewController.swift вызывают эту модель так:

```
var btData: BTData!
    btData = BTData()
```

И у меня не получается во ViewController передать статусное сообщение в Label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы во ViewController получать данные от модели об изменении значений переменных традиционно используется несколько методов:

**Делегат:**

код в модели:

```
//перед объявлением класса
protocol DataDelegate {
    func didUpdateData(data:String)
}

//в классе

var delegate: DataDelegate?

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager!) {
    switch (central.state)
    {
         //...
         delegate?.didUpdateData(statusMsg)
    }

}
```

код в контроллере:

```
var model: Model

//где то, например в ините, создать модель и объявись себя делегатом     
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.model = Model()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    model.delegate = self
}

//а вот сюда приходят данные из модели
func didUpdateData(data: String) {
    self.label?.text = data
}
```

**Блок** (может течь память, не проверил)

в модели:

```
var dataUpdateBlock:(String)->(Void) = {_ in return} // объявить блок в классе

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager!) {
    switch (central.state)
    {
         //...
         dataUpdateBlock(statusMsg)
     }

}
```

в контроллере:

```
    //задать, что должен делать блок. где то в ините или во viewDidLoad
    model.dataUpdateBlock = { (data:String) in
        self.label?.text = data //тут может течь память :(
    }
```

**key-value observer** (если модель унаследована от NSObject)

в модели:

```
public dynamic var statusMsg: String = "" //добавить dynamic в объявление перменной
```

в контроллере:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //добавить обсервер после присвоения модели
    model.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "statusMsg", options: .New, context: nil) 
}

//эта функция будет вызываться каждый раз когда statusMsg меняет значение 
//(кроме первого присвоения, потому что оно случится до объявления обсервера)
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if keyPath == "statusMsg" {
        self.label?.text = "\(change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey])"
    }
}

//не забыть убрать обсервер
deinit {
    model.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "statusMsg")
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую как раз делегаты для передачи значения, полученного по блутуз в контроллер!

Comment: Пробую делегат. А xcode ругается вот так _Cannot assign a value of type 'ViewController' to a value of type 'numberOfRevolutionsDelegate?'_ на эту строчку **btData.delegateRevolutions = self**. Т.е. нужно было этот тип протокола объявить в классе контроллера написал так **class ViewController: UIViewController, numberOfRevolutionsDelegate**. Но опять же ошибка _Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'numberOfRevolutionsDelegate'_

Comment: в декларацию вью контроллера добавить протокол, через запятую после суперкласса: `MyController: UIViewController, DelegateHere`

Comment: Я так и писал. Но была ошибка. И я понял почему. Ошибка была до объявления функции в контроллере куда приходят данные.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге получилось сделать при помощи NSNotificaton. Результат показан ниже.
Так выглядит код в модели, отвечающий за сбор сообщений:

```
func sendBTServiceNotification(BTStatus: String) {
    var connectionDetails = ["Статус": BTStatus]
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(BLEServiceStatusNotification, object: self, userInfo: connectionDetails)
}

// Получаем состояние при обновлении Central Manager (обязательная)
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager!) {
    switch (central.state)
    {
    case .Unsupported:
        sendBTServiceNotification("BLE не поддерживается")
        break
    case .Unauthorized:
        sendBTServiceNotification("Приложение не авторизовано для использования BLE")
        break
    case .Unknown:
        sendBTServiceNotification("Состояние Central Manager не известно")
        break
    case .Resetting:
        sendBTServiceNotification("Соединение с системным сервисом потеряно")
        break
    case .PoweredOff:
        sendBTServiceNotification("BLE выключено")
        break
    case .PoweredOn:
        startScanning()
    default:
        break
    }
}

func startScanning() {
    sendBTServiceNotification("Сканирование...")
    if let central = centralManager {
        central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
    }
}
```

А так выглядит ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    btData = BTData()

    // Читаем статус BLE
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("statusChanged:"), name: btData.BLEServiceStatusNotification, object: nil)

}

deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: btData.BLEServiceStatusNotification, object: nil)
}

// Обновляем статус BLE
func statusChanged(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo as! [String: String]
    let statusMsg: String! = userInfo["Статус"]
    Status.text = "Статус: \(statusMsg)"
}
```

Comment: вот теперь я понял что хотели сделать :)

Comment: Я бы сказал, что `NSNotification` здесь не лучший вариант. Его лучше использовать если либо несколько модулей подписаны обсерверами, либо когда отправитель не знает, кто на него подписан. Традиционно для передачи данных модель-контроллер используется (1) делегат, (2) блок (3) KVO. Ну или если не лень разобраться с reactiveCocoa то там вообще все очень просто.

Comment: Спасибо! Про KVO слышал, но не пробовал применить. Попробую сделать на предложенных вариантах.

Comment: Все классы наследованные от NSObject совместимы с KVO; для классов не наследованных от NSObject в Swift посмотрите 'Property Observers'