# Непрерывная передача данных меду контроллерами

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Имеются два контроллера Vc1 и Vc2. При открытии Vc2 нужно забирать (получать) непрерывный поток информации  из Vc1.
Например: Vc1 непрерывно преобразует данные от альтиметра (барометр). В Vc2 - окно с настройками получает (забирает) информацию от Vc1 и отображает ее на своем Вью.
Как это организовать?

Comment: в ответах на этот вопрос описаны 4 варианта как это можно сделать (делегат, блок, KVO, нотификейшн).  http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448436/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B0-bluetooth-%D0%B2-viewcontroller/451155

Comment: а для вашей ситуации рекомендовал бы не использовать вью контроллер как модель для другого контроллера, а вынести преобразование данных в отдельный класс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ это "увести" переменную (или несколько) в AppDelegate и все.

VC1 записывает данные в "верхнюю" переменную:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;
```

Ну и  VC2 просто вычитывает эту переменную:

```
 AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
_managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
```

Можно так же VC1 сделать делегатом и брать непосретсвенно из VC1, можно протокол объявить. Можно вызывать в VC1 методы из VC2.

Выбирайт, все зависит от того что удобнее, предпочтительнее и привычнее.

Comment: если вы хотите синглтон, так и сделайте себе синглтон. Не надо appDelegate захламлять, он там не для этого положен.

Comment: Так и поступил. Объявил переменную в AppDelegate.h В двух контроллерах "дергаю" пременную как написал dark_Haron, все работает. Вопрос, на сколько это корректно и правильно?

Comment: @Oleg я отвечу аллегорией: делайте именно так, если у вас минимум две пары рук - одну вам скоро оторвут :)